# Diablo 3 - can't press escape key

Tags: diablo-iii, keyboard

I'm experiencing a strange problem in D3. I can't press escape to bring up the menu. It's only been happening for the last week.

> Try rebinding the key.

Yeah, I've tried to do that but the rebind key is a different colour and it looks like it's disabled.

> Maybe your keyboard/esc key is broken?

No, I've tried the escape key outside of D3 and it works fine. I've also got several keys assigned to my G keys (thanks G13 gameboard) and they don't work either.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is it a patch error?

**Edit:**

> I've found that if I press Shift+Esc it brings ups the menu. I don't
>   think it's possible that the shift key is stuck on because I wouldn't
>   be able to move if the shift key was stuck down

Comment: Not me. It's a bit hard to tell without knowing what are installed on your computer. I suspect it's a problem specific to you.

Comment: I had this once... when you hit escape it minimizes instead of menu.  If that is the case, that is a toggled on option caused (and fixed) by hitting ALT + ESC (hope that helps... there's a chance)

Comment: I've also tried resetting the keybindings to default... that didn't work either :( I don't think I have any keys toggled...

Comment: I hope you've posted this in the official forum as well just to enhance your chance of getting some help. Have tried to change from fullscreen to windowed mode and then back? Does it work in windowed mode?

Comment: Maybe you have another key that is stuck? IE. Alt, Ctril or Shift? It might do something like that.

Comment: It might be that another program captures the key. I had a simmilar problem with [Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495050/how-can-i-use-alt-as-meta-key-in-windows-for-emacs-23-especially-m-x) and Growl was the problem. Have you installed new applications recently? Try hitting ESC while out of Diablo and check what it actually does.

Comment: Wrote a short script to test if Escape key has the right code on your end: http://jsbin.com/atagom/5/
Go to the page and press escape. The correct keycode for escape is 27.

Comment: @Bora Weird, I'm on a different computer and it isn't working... Other keys work and CTRL+ESC brings up the start menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My brother had that problem with minecraft turns out the problem was a program runining in the background was disabling the escape key.

Comment: Could be a setting in your Logitech SetPoint where it's disabling it? Does the Windows key work also?

Comment: Hey Alarick, welcome to arqade. I'm going to give this one to you because you're the most right answer. I restarted the computer and that seems to have fixed it...

Comment: @Coomie if restarting it honestly fixed the problem.  It might have been sticky keys on Windows XP (assuming you are using that).  It would make sense if holding shift would fix it under the scenario.  IDK how many times I had to end a game of SC2 or other games cause of Sticky Keys.  You can use this to kill it http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=1498 and hopefully that fixes it for good!

Comment: @Falcon165o I'm on windows 7 and I don't think it was sticky keys because wouldn't that mean shift was toggled on? In D3 I wouldn't have been able to move.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Photoshop up and running while playing Diablo 3, the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key doesn't work. Closing Photoshop while running Diablo 3 will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Also verify that Stick Keys is not enabled.  I know that is a pesky problem that can occur from time to time to ruin gaming on Windows Computers.